# Node, vite insanly slow request speed and high memory usage

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vite

**Backstory:**
I was converting our vue + webpack setup to vue 3 + Vite, everything worked great for couple of weeks.

A few weeks later around late december 2023 we wanted to start testing the whole project if everthing worked. I just got a new laptop for a week (working on the webpack setup) doing fine. Switched to the upgrade branch en Vite was insanly slow. Taking up 30 seconds to load and also timeout requests. Watching file changes also took around 10 seconds, or just froze.

So for the time being, I used my old laptop which was still working normal. I did not do any windows updates since I went back to my old laptop until today. And everything is slow again with high memory usage.

**Problem:**
Problem after windows 10 updates between early december 2023 and january 2024.
Vite page requests take up to 5 seconds, instead of 20ms. Using the direct vue component url.
Vite can barely see any file modifications or takes up to 10 seconds.
Nodes uses 2GB RAM after 15 minutes running and continues to grow. Before maybe 500MB max.

**Tested versions:**
Vite v5.0.10
npm v9.6.0
Node v16, v20.10, v20.11
Laravel v10.39.0, plugin v1.0.1

**Other**

- Chcked for more windows updates
- Running `npm run dev` outside of phpstorm and administrator
- Same problem on 2 different laptops
- Coworkers on mac have no problems at all
- A new laravel + breeze setup seems to be workig fine

[image: High memory usage node]
[image: Slow loading times vite component]

Comment: It's unclear if you blame this on windows updates or not

Comment: There could be many reasons. But at this point of time that was the only change that happend before the bug. It could be just a setting that maybe changed. I cannot find the cause of the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest to try more Windows machines. The question is too broad and unspecific. How is Laravel related? In case it is relevant, this limits possible feedback because this is much more exotic setup than vanilla Vite. "Node v16, v20.10, v20.11" - what does this mean, did you switch multiple versions? Unless this is a known performance issue that's already discussed in Vite repo with (the first thing to check), you can't get much help from the outside as the problem needs to be reproducible. Removing and reinstalling node_modules (especially node_modules/.cache/) can help, did you try that?

Comment: Vite 5 is too fresh, there always can be problems with new major releases, since a bundler has a lot of moving parts with a lot to break. Vite 4 is more mature with a lot of more experience how it works, I'd suggest to try to downgrade if you need a chance to fix it the easy way. Notice that 5 doesn't support Node 16, don't know how its usage can affect the way it works

Comment: I have found the problem. In the `tailwind.config.js` was require still begin used to import the packages. Changed it to import and it works fine now on both laptops. I worked with the require for 3 weeks straigh with multiple npm installs. No idea why it just decided to stop working after an update.

Comment: Sorry for the broad question I did not know where I should look. Since it throwed no errors anywhere. Just stacking up the RAM and slow refresh times.